# How do I trigger my redux function in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd

I have a form that is supposed to create a new user on submit. On `handleCreate` I need redux to trigger the `addUser` action and update the state thereby creating a new user but I don't seem to be calling the action correctly.

action.js

```
 const addUser = payload => ({
    payload,
    type: ADD_USER,
});
```

reducer.js

```
const addUsers = (items, newItem) => {
    const { id } = newItem;
    items[id] = newItem;
    return { ...items };
};

       case ADD_USER: {
            const { users } = state;
            const { payload: { item } } = action;
            return {
                ...state,
                isUpdated: true,
                users: addUsers(users, item),
            };
        }
```

The function to trigger the action in the component

```
    handleCreate = () => {
        const { form } = this.formRef.props;
        const { addUser } = this.props.actions;
        form.validateFields((error, values) => {
            if (error) {
                return error;
            }
            form.resetFields();
            const user = {
                age: values.age,
                birthday: values[DATE_PICKER].format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                firstName: values.firstName,
                hobby: values.hobby,
                id: uuid(),
                lastName: values.lastName,
            };
            addUser(user);
        });
    };
```

Comment: can you add the code for the `addUser` action please ?

Comment: I have added it @Taki

Comment: what does your connect and mapStateToProps function look like?

Comment: In the code sandbox you linked below, if you add a console log in the reducer the ADD_USER action is being dispatched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is with destructuring the playload,  `const { payload: { item } } = action;` expects the `payload` to have a key `item`

```js
const action = {
  payload: {
    item: {
      a: "a",
      b: "b"
    }
  }
};

const {
  payload: { item }
} = action;

console.log(item)
```

replace `const { payload: { item } } = action;` in your reducer with

`const { payload: item } = action;`

Comment: Not yet. Does not trigger.

Comment: can you add `mapDispatchToProps` ?

Comment: The component is connected. Here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Simpcyclassy/user_form/tree/feature-Chioma-add-redux) . /src/components/users.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your actual project linked in the comments of the other answer, I found the source of your problem, your reducer for ADD_USER needs to be

```
    case ADD_USER: {
      const { users } = state;
      return {
        ...state,
        isUpdated: true,
        users: addUsers(users, action.payload)
      };
    }
```

Before when you had `const { payload: { item } } = action;` you were expecting the action object to be shaped

```
{
   type: WHATEVER_TYPE,
   payload: { item: user }
},
```

But the action actually looks like

```
{
   type: WHATEVER_TYPE,
   payload: user,
},
```